VS Code terminal is inconsistent with normal terminal MacOS ARM
Below I have attached two images. One from my VS Code terminal and the other one from my normal terminal. The difference is important because I keep getting dependency issues due to the packages being compiled for x86_64 instead of Arm64 which is what it should be.
What is the discrepancy due to and how can I ensure they both are using Arm64?
When I run this it seems both are available in my python installation
file $(which python3)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64]
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3 (for architecture x86_64):       Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3 (for architecture arm64):        Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64

Any help would be much appreciated!



I finally solved it. Needed to force it to use python3 every time I call it by adding the following to ~/.bash_profile:
export PYTHON_ARCH="arm64"
alias python3="arch -arm64 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3"
alias pip3="arch -arm64 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip3"

Hopefully this will help someone else.
